# Mercurial .hgignore

Tags: mercurial, glob, hgignore

I need to ignore all files in whole project tree, versioned by Mercurial, that starts with specific character. Let's say underscore (or it may be some other).

I searched on google a lot, but I cannot find right glob syntax. I found [glob expression test environment](http://www.globtester.com/), where I could try patterns, but nothing works for me.

Consider following project structure:

```
/function/_backup/file1.php
/function/_backup/file2.php
/function/Class/A.php
/function/Class/_B.php
/_graph/1.jpg
/.hgignore
/.htaccess
/_index.php
/index.php
```

The only files that I need to propagate to repository are `A.php`, `.htaccess` and `index.php`.

The question is: how should my .hgignore look like?

Answer (score 1):

You should add the following line to `.hgignore`:

```
glob:_*
```

Comment: This is not working.. Currently my .hgignore looks like this: `\.orig$`, `\.conflict\~$` and few other generated. I added `\.hgignore$`, but I don't know how exactly should I add the rule for the file/dir that starts with specific character..

Comment: @tcigler Can you post your current `.hgignore` content? I tried adding the line I posted in my answer in a test repo, and every file or directory that starts with an underscore is ignored by Mercurial.

Comment: I tried it now on different project as a new .hgignore file and the content is only: `\.hgignore$` on first line, which successfully ignores hgignore itself (obviously) and your suggested `glob:_*` on second line and this is not working..